# Accessing web content with ffmpeg on android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ffmpeg, dns

I'm using ffmpeg inside my xamarin.android project,by accessing a statically build version for the corresponding architecture of the device. 
I'm using https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/, static builds which support https protocol.
I'm calling ffmpeg by starting a new process and passing the arguments.Here is a pseudo code for the operation:

```
arguments = {'-i',inputFileName,...}
run('./ffmpeg',arguments,redirectOutput = true,...)
     .OnOutput(s) => log(s)
```

Now,I want to access a file in the web, directly with ffmpeg, since from my testing it is more efficient in term of bandwidth, and speed.

The problem i'm facing is that because i'm using a static build of ffmpeg, we need to statically link gclib, which results loss of dns resolution as stated in the readme:

> A limitation of statically linking glibc is the loss of DNS resolution. Installing
>                nscd through your package manager will fix this or you can use
>                `"ffmpeg -i http://<ip address here>/"` instead of `"ffmpeg -i http://example.com/"`

But the content that i'm trying to get provides strictly only through HTTPS,so there is no way to access it via the ip.
But on Linux systems i had no problem accessing the content(With the same command as for android), thanks to nscd, which isn't present in android.

- Is there anyway to use android's dns resolution?
- Or compile ffmpeg
  differently, as stated in this
  [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/15109)?Maybe using android
  NDK would default this?Would ffmpeg even work then?
- Or somehow pipe the content, to
  ffmpeg's stdin, and tell it to input from pipe (Would it still be
  more efficient, than downloading and saving the file, then running
  ffmpeg ) ?

All suggestions are welcomed!

## EDIT

As for SushiHangover advice, i was able to implement it via piping,i came up with two ways:

```
Process ffmpegProcess = new Process();
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = ....
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
ffmpegProcess.Start();

//Way 1
var data = await GetBytesAsync();
await ffmpegProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream.WriteAsync(b, 0,b.Length);

// Way 2
await (await GetStreamAsync()).CopyToAsync(ffmpegProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream);
```

Which both work, but they aren't efficient in term of bandwidth as ffmpeg itself, i tested the network traffic with NetBalancer.

Way 1 (Fresh Data - First time running program) :  401 KB Upload/ 19.7 MB Download
Way 1 (Second time running program) :  334.3 KB Upload/ 17.7 MB Download
Way 2 (Second time running program) :  370 KB Upload/ 16.6 MB Download
Through FFmpeg Only (Fresh Data - First time running program): 142.4 KB Upload / 5.3 MB Download
Through FFmpeg Only (Second time running program): 67.5 KB Upload / 3.7 MB Download

Who can i overcome the gap ? I speculate that ffmpeg only reads the headers, and able to download only the needed audio stream based on my arguments, rather than the whole video as my snippets do.

Comment: If your ffmpeg version is compiled with pipe support (check via `-protocols` option), you could do a https stream to stdin and start ffpeg reading from `pipe:0` or use tcp and pipe to a local port and have ffmpeg read from that port.

Comment: @SushiHangover I do have pipe support with ffmpeg, but i was not able to get a working example by myself. If you can, i would love an example/proof of concept, especially in the opening of the https stream.